# Sum distinct values in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to sum distinct values (highlighted ones) in Tableau 10.5. Here is the picture how my table looks like

[image]

This is what I want

[image]

This is what I have tried and I am getting

```
{ FIXED [Cd Year], [Supplies]  : SUM([Quantity]) }
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: This would help you https://community.tableau.com/thread/150190

Comment: You don't need a LOD calc for this, or any calc. Just put Status on the Filter shelf and exclude Delivered. Then drop Quantity on the Text shelf. Save writing LOD calcs for when the dimensions in the view are different from the value you want to calculate. That will be more flexible and performant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements within your FIXED statement do not exclude the values where the Status is 'Delivered'. You will need to either filter the initial data to remove the 'Delivered' Status, or add an additional element to the FIXED formula.

Something like the following will be of use:

```
{FIXED [Cd Year], [Supplies]: SUM(IF [Status] = "Delivered" THEN 0 ELSE [Quantity] END)}
```

You may also benefit from Context Filters : https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/filtering_context.htm

Comment: thanks for reply. Is there is any other solution? I just shared the few data I may other values in status column where having the duplicates.

Comment: I can't provide anything further without further information. You may have to amend the criteria in the IF statement to fit your needs (i.e. maybe you want Status to be one of a few values and to SUM Quantity in those cases rather than excluding Delivered as I have done above?). If that is the case, swap the THEN and ELSE around.

Answer (score 2):

exclude 'Delivered' in filter and you will get the required output like below.